# WebView as a Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is there a way to set a WebView as a Live Wallpaper?
Any links/hints greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this, all you get is a Canvas.

Comment: hey @Romanian can you please help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-and-skip-the-wallpaper-chooser I saw that you are Android Engineer at Google so you might know the answer. Thanks.