# backup and restore home screen widgets and live wallpaper

Tags: android, android-widget, live-wallpaper, android-backup-service

My clients wants me to create an app which will install some apps, a 3rd party launcher, some widgets in home screen and a live wallpaper. All of these with least user interactions. So that he can replicate all of the settings in multiple devices by just installing one app.

Installing apps part is done, launcher's backup is also restored. But, it can't restore the widgets that were set on the main device. Same for the live wallpaper. I searched for the solution of both problems, but I couldn't find it. Is there any way to do it?

The devices will be rooted, so you can also suggest a solution that requires root.

Comment: Check out this answer for setting wallpaper without user interaction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683464/set-live-wallpaper-programmatically-on-rooted-device-android